# add mobile prefix in existing mobile field in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have mysql table 'USERS' which have a column name 'MOBILE" which contains customer mobile numbers in following format

```
333123456
333123457
```

I want to add 092 in starting of every number so that it should be like this

```
092333123456
092333123457
```

there are hundreds of mobile records I have to update, so is tehre any query I can run to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `UPDATE` should suffice. Make sure your column isn't a numeric type or you will lose leading zeroes.

```
UPDATE USERS SET MOBILE = CONCAT('092', MOBILE)
```

Also think about the possibility of keeping the prefix on a separate column, it would be easier to update and it won't be mixed up with the actual mobile number.

Comment: I'd recommend to add `WHERE LENGTH(mobile) = 9` and/or `WHERE LEFT(mobile, 3) != '092'`. Whether it is not enough that can happen...

Comment: it worked well. what if want to remove 092 from all mobile numbers (only if the mobiel number starts with 092) ??

Comment: @iBBi in that case use `UPDATE USERS SET MOBILE = RIGHT(MOBILE, LENGTH(MOBILE) - 3) WHERE MOBILE LIKE '092%'`

Comment: I am trying to remove question mark ? which is in mobile number , how can i remove ? character from phone number?

Comment: i tried update rm_users set mobile = REPLACE(mobile,'?',''); but nto worked

Comment: @iBBi seems that your query should have worked. Please post it as another question.